# AngularJS Scope and tab directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs, scopes

I just can't get how AngularJS scope works.

I have an **ui-tabs** *Directive*, with a ***tab controller***. This is supposed to handle tabbed content.

This tab directive can contains 2 others directive, **heading-template** *Directive*, which is the template for the tab heading, and **tab-pane** *Directive*, which is the panes to show/hide.

The tab directive can have 2 behaviors : if the attr `templated` is on the element, then we use an *empty template*, and we will use later the **heading-template** *Directive* to generate tabs heading.

Else, we use a template which generates ul list with each panes title.

The problem is the **heading-template** *Directive* : this *Directive* simply binds the **ng-repeat** *Directive* to the template and compiles it.

But I can't have access to the `scope.panes`, which are located in ***Tab Directive's controller*** `scope`. The directive simply don't find them, and I don't understand why.

Here's the JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/whitep4nther/mwk9gp9x/

Thank you for your help, I'm turning crazy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lately, I found a lot of people have problems with the same root cause:

The `ng-transclude` doesn't work in a way that you are expecting.

It's by design that content added via `ng-transclude` will be binded with an outer (original) scope, not a scope of the current element that `ng-transclude` is on.

In your case the content added via `ng-transclude` in `templated-heading.tpl.html` will be binded with the `$rootScope`, not the isolate scope of `uiTabs` directive.

If you want the transcluded content to be binded with the isolate scope, you could use a modified version of `ng-tranclude` like this:

```
.directive('myTransclude', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controllers, transcludeFn) {
      transcludeFn(scope, function(nodes) {
        element.empty();
        element.append(nodes);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

And use it in the template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/templated-heading.tpl.html">
  <div class="ui-tabs" my-transclude>
  </div>
</script>
```

**Example JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/a7fjb9sr/1/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although I already found the same solution. I must admit it's very confusing when you start, but now it seems clearer.